# Using CSS calc() in App Style Layout with Footer

Tags: css, overflow, calc

I'm trying to use CSS calc() to build an App Style layout with a footer at the bottom.

The main CSS players:

```
.content-container {
    height: calc(100% - 110px);
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left, .right {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.left {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.right {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.right-content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Here's a quick overview of the HTML:

```
<div class="content-container">
<div class="left">
    <h1>left</h1>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="right-title">
        TITLE OF THE SECTION
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
        <div class="group">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Please view the full example here:
http://codepen.io/woocas/pen/MwyBGd?editors=110

I'm trying to make the overflow in the .right div (the yellow one) take the height of the .content-container.

But as you can see in the example, the scrollbar goes beyond the space allocated to it by content-container. It's behind the footer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean `.right > .right-content`? Not the `.right div`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the CSS heights in your right column to percentage values since they're embedded in a container they'll always present in a fit manner?

```
.right-title {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 65%;
}
.right-content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 35%;
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that I need the top to be fixed. But I think you set me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could do another calc on the **.right** height and add a margin-bottom, so that **.right** will not go beyond the **footer**, but the whole thing seems to be a bit over-complicated.

```
    .right {
        width: 30%;
        background-color: yellow;
        height: calc(100% - 90px);
        padding-bottom: 90px;
    }
```

Comment: I know! I'm trying to simplify it. Right now they are doing calculations with javascript. I'm trying to convince them there's a way to do it just in CSS but I can't seem to fully get it.

I read you can't use calc within a calc. Not supported by the spec.

Thanks though.